# 401 Unauthorized react axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, redux-toolkit

I am trying to make an ecommerce using react, redux toolkit and axios
the problem is that I want the user to log in and get his cart from the backend right after the login
it always fails the and says (unauthorized) when i first login because it can't find the token
then after refresh it says unauthorized one more time
after the third refresh it works

this is my get cart

```
export const getCart = createAsyncThunk("cart/getcart", async () => {
  const response = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/techcart/get_cart/", {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
    },
  });

  return response.data;
});
const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState: {
    cart: [],
    cartItemsIds :[],
  },

builder.addCase(getCart.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.cart = action.payload;
```

and this is my login function

```
export const login = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/login",
  async ({ email, password }, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/techcart/login/",

        { username: email, password }
      );
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
      
      return response.data;
      
    } catch (error) {}
  }
);
const initialState = user
  ? { isLoggedIn: true, user }
  : { isLoggedIn: false, user: null };


  builder.addCase(login.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.isLoggedIn = true;
      state.user = action.payload;
```

here is where i am doing the login

```
const HandleLogin = () => {
    dispatch(login({ email, password }));

  };

  useEffect(()=> {
    if(isLoggedIn){
      navigate('/')
      dispatch(getCart())
    }
  },[isLoggedIn])
```

Cart page

```
  useEffect(() => {

    dispatch(getCart());
    
  }, []);
```

here is where im defining my token :

```
export let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) :  null;
export let userId = user ?  user.user_id : null;
export let token = user!=null ? user.token : null;
```

and here is where im importing it in my cart slice

```
import { user, token } from "../../constants";
```

im using redux persist to persist the state of my cart

if anyone can help me i'm so thankful
[here is what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xsfD.png)

Comment: How do you retrieve & store `token`?

Comment: token is stored in local storage when i login with user's information

`export let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) :  null;
export let token = user!=null ? user.token : null;

`
here is how i'm retrieving it

Comment: I don't see this part in your `getCart`!

Comment: its in another file  "constants"  and i'm just importing it in my cart slice

Comment: You should update your code with this part, because the issue should come from here, how you retrieve your token :)

Comment: I mean, update your question, so we can see the code and maybe point the issue :)

Comment: I did update it

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing your token directly when your js is executed. So when you retrieve it, it is undefined.
Ans when you do the login, you're indeed storing your token, but you're not updating it in your application.

I can see you're using redux, so store your token in your redux store, and before sending your api call to retrieve your cart, retrieve your token from redux, to always have the latest value of your token